# Bootbox is not defined in javascript in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bootbox

I'm creating a chrome extension to display a button, which when clicked displays a feedback form using bootbox in javascript.

When I load the extension into chrome, the first time the button gets clicked, I get bootbox not defined error.
From thereon, if I reload the page everything works fine.

This is the code where I use bootbox.

```
var box = bootbox.dialog({
    size: "small",
    title: "Enter your feedback",
    backdrop: true,
    closeButton: true,
    message: ...........
```

Comment: where do you include the script reference for bootbox?

Comment: I'm adding a listener to onHistoryStateUpdated in background script which executes the content script to add button on the page.

Comment: Let me guess. The library is loaded via manifest `content_scripts` key, and the code above by `executeScript`. Correct?

Comment: Yes. In manifest, I add this line under content_scripts
"js":["libraries/jquery.js","libraries/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js","libraries/bootbox.min.js","content_script.js"]
and in background scipt i use `executeScript`